# Same read- and write-stream in collectionFS using graphicsmagick

Tags: javascript, meteor, graphicsmagick, collectionfs

I need to manipulate an image using `graphicsmagick`.

My FSCollection looks like this:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("media", {
    stores: [
        new FS.Store.FileSystem("anything"),
        new FS.Store.FileSystem("something")
    ],
});
```

My problem is, that the writeStream should be the same like the readStream. And this doesn't work as this leads to an empty result:

```
var read  = file.createReadStream('anything'),
    write = file.createWriteStream('anything');

gm(read)
    .crop(100,100,10,10)
.stream()
.on('end',function(){ console.log('done'); })
.on('error',function(err){ console.warn(err); })
.pipe(write, function (error) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    else console.log('ok');
});
```

Comment: You can't read from and write to the same file at the same time like this; effectively you would be overwriting parts of the file while you were still reading from it. Best bet is to write to a separate file and then rename it once you're done.

Comment: @ExplosionPills That makes sense :-) I'm not very familiar working with streams. How can I use a temporary file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simultaneously reading from and writing to the same file is not possible since you would be overwriting content at the same time you were trying to read from it. Write to a different file and then rename it to the original.

```
var read  = file.createReadStream('anything'),
    write = file.createWriteStream('anything-writeTo');

gm(read)
    .crop(100,100,10,10)
.stream()
.on('error',function(err){ console.warn(err); })
.pipe(write, function (error) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    else console.log('ok');
})
.on('end',function(){
    file.rename("anything-writeTo", "anything", function (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        else console.log('rename complete');
    });
})
```

Comment: This gives me `ReferenceError: fs is not defined`. Can I use the stores 'anything' and 'something' (like shown in my example code) and rename 'something' to 'anything'? I mean 'anything-writeTo' should be 'something'...

Comment: @user3848987 changed to `file` instead of `fs`. You can use whatever names you want, but the idea is that you wouldn't try to write to an existing file.

Comment: fs = Npm.require('fs');